# JMeter connect timeout and retries

Tags: http, jmeter, timeout, connection-timeout

Using JMeter 5.1.1 I'm trying to abort an HTTP request if the timeout elapses when attempting to connect. I set the **connect timeout** to 5000ms in the Advanced tab of the  HTTP Request.

The problem is that the connect time in the View Results in Table shows 15000ms, which makes me think that it retries twice when failing. Whatever connect timeout I put, I always get 3x the value in the results.

Is it because it retries, if yes, how can I change this settings to NOT retry?

Answer (score 0):

Retries is managed by:

- httpclient4.retrycount

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#httpclient4

Comment: That property is not set and therefore has its default value 0. So it must be something else. Also, according to the doc, it seems to operate on the HTTP layer (to tell success of failure).